# How to Add key in App Setting tag of web config with special character like '&'

Tags: asp.net, web-config, appsettings

I tried to add this value but it is giving me the error

```
<add key="RssFeedURL" value="http://www.example.com/?cat=11&feed=rss2"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could encode it:

```
<add key="RssFeedURL" value="http://www.example.com/?cat=11&amp;feed=rss2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks its working :) i can't able to mark it as answer rigth now, but thanks for your help.